# ¿Por qué se puede instanciar esta interfaz?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Set <Cliente> clientesBanco = new HashSet <Cliente>();
```

¿Por qué estoy instanciando las interfaz *set* si las interfaces no se pueden instanciar?

Comment: Las interfaces se pueden instanciar. el objeto, va a contener solamente propiedades y metodos del tipo set.

Comment: Pero estoy instanciando la interfaz Set y usando el constructor del HashSet ¿cómo es eso posible?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html HashSet implementa la interfaz. Mira aca y si te sirve, probamos a hacer una traduccion de lo que dicen por alla. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947841/73749

Comment: A partir de java 8 se introdujeron una gran cantidad de cambios que antes no se podían hacer.

Comment: Deberías de ver el concepto de polimorfismo en Java.

Comment: @AndyC Este código compila desde Java 5, no tiene nada de especial

Comment: A partir de las interfaces no se pueden crear objetos, si a eso te referís con que no se pueden instanciar. Lo que sí se puede, es que una instancia de interfaz sea una referencia en memoria que apunte a un objeto de una clase que implemente dicha interfaz. O sea, la instancia no se transforma en objeto, sino en referencia a un objeto, que va a ser una instancia de una clase que tenga en su implementación a dicha interfaz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes entender esta línea de código así:

```
Set<Cliente> clientesBanco=new HashSet<Cliente>();
```

- Se está declarando una variable de tipo `Set<Cliente>` llamada `clientesBanco`.
- A dicha variable se le asigna la instancia de una clase que cumple (implementa) la interfaz `Set<Cliente>`.
- Dicha clase es `HashSet<Cliente>`.